# I am getting java.lang.NullPointerException while sending driver object of test instance to listener on test failure. Appreciate Quick response

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, listener

Base class code:

---

package resources;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.time.Duration;

import java.util.Properties;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;

import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Base {

public WebDriver driver;

public Properties prop;

public WebDriver InitializeDriver() throws IOException {

prop = new Properties();

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(

"C:\Users\user\eclipse-workspace\E2EProjectS\src\main\java\resources\data.properties");

prop.load(fis);

String BrowserName = prop.getProperty("browser");

System.out.println(BrowserName);

if (BrowserName.equals("chrome")) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Selenium\Drivers\chromedriver.exe");

driver = new ChromeDriver();

} else if (BrowserName.equals("firefox")) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.driver", "C:\Selenium\Drivers\geckodriver.exe");

driver = new FirefoxDriver();

} else if (BrowserName.equals("Edge")) {

// System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\Selenium\Drivers\.exe");

driver = new EdgeDriver();

}

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(15));

driver.manage().window().maximize();

return driver;

}

public void GetScreenshot(String TestcaseName, WebDriver driver) throws IOException {

TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;

File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

String DestinationFile = System.getProperty("User.dir"+"\reports\" + TestcaseName+".png");

FileUtils.copyFile(source, new File(DestinationFile));

}

}

Listeners Class code:

---

package testCases;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.testng.ITestContext;

import org.testng.ITestListener;

import org.testng.ITestResult;

import resources.Base;

public class Listeners extends Base implements ITestListener{

@Override

public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {

WebDriver driver = null;

String MethodName = result.getMethod().getMethodName();

try {

driver =(WebDriver)result.getTestClass().getRealClass().getDeclaredField("driver").get(result.getInstance());

} catch (Exception e) {

}

try {

GetScreenshot(MethodName,driver);

} catch (IOException e) {

e.printStackTrace();

}

}

}

testng XML code:

---

Logs:

---

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.6.0

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".

SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

chrome

Starting ChromeDriver 102.0.5005.61 (0e59bcc00cc4985ce39ad31c150065f159d95ad3-refs/branch-heads/5005@{#819}) on port 52887

Only local connections are allowed.

Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.

ChromeDriver was started successfully.

[1658152019.523][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 103.

Jul 18, 2022 7:16:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession

INFO: Detected upstream dialect: W3C

Jul 18, 2022 7:16:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch

WARNING: Unable to find an exact match for CDP version 103, so returning the closest version found: 102

Jul 18, 2022 7:16:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch

INFO: Found CDP implementation for version 103 of 102

java.lang.NullPointerException

at java.base/java.io.File.(File.java:278)

at resources.Base.GetScreenshot(Base.java:53)

at testCases.Listeners.onTestFailure(Listeners.java:38)

at org.testng.internal.TestListenerHelper.runTestListeners(TestListenerHelper.java:99)

at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.runTestResultListener(TestInvoker.java:277)

at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:978)

at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:194)

at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)

at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)

at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)

at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:806)

at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:601)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:433)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:427)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:387)

at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:330)

at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)

at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)

at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1256)

at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1176)

at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1099)

at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1067)

at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)

at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)

at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

Comment: Can you please share a working snippet via github repo so that this issue can be debugged & identified? I can only see the Base  Class & Listenerts impl and without your Test Class details, this issue can hardly be reproduced.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).